# Minimum Weight Path

Tags: graph, dynamic-programming, graph-algorithm, minimax

"Given a connected undirected weighted graph, find the maximum weight of the edge in the path from s to t where the maximum weight of the edges in the path is the minimum."

This seems like a Floyd–Warshall algorithm problem. Is there an approach faster than O(V^3)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I submit that a breadth first search (BFS) to determine whether `s` is connected to `t` by any path can run in *O(V)* time, since each vertex need only be visited once.

I propose therefore, that the solution to this problem is to sort the edges by weight, and then

```
while the BFS succeeds in finding a path from s to t
    remove the highest weighted edge from the graph
```

The last edge to be removed before the BFS fails is the maximum weighted edge that you're looking for.

Total running time is *O(E log E)* to sort the edges by weight, plus *O(VE)* to run the BFS until removing an edge disconnects the graph.